# How do I build and run android app from CLI?

Tags: android, gradle, command-line-interface, android-databinding, gradlew

So I have an android project setup and I am using **Kotlin** as primary language. I have also used **Databinding Library** from Jetpack. Out of curiosity, I tried to build the app from CLI. The application is building and running fine from the GUI, Run button. As far as I know I can build and run from the CLI too, right?
So I ran

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

and I was not able to build the application. I got the following output on my terminal:

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.ServiceLoaderLite.loadImplementations(ServiceLoaderLite.kt:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.ServiceLoaderLite.loadImplementations(ServiceLoaderLite.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension$loadProcessors$efficientProcessorLoader$1.doLoadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors(ProcessorLoader.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors$default(ProcessorLoader.kt:28)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.loadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:89)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:172)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:81)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:555)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:546)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1558)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 43 more
```

Now I am guessing, this error has something to do with Databinding but I could be wrong. I also tried to look at some open source android projects using CI/CD in their projects to see what they are doing but I could not find one which uses DataBinding library. All they had was the same two three gradle scripts which are not running for me. Do suggest me a solution to this so that I will be able to build and run my application from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what turns out is JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding) seems missing in Java 11 which was being used in my system. When I did `java -version` on my terminal, I got **Open JDK 11** which was located in `usr/lib/jvm/`. So I went ahead and removed it.

```
 sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Then I installed Java 8 Open JDK

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

Now I have java 8 which is also used by Android Studio and has the JAXB api. Do correct me if I am wrong as this is a self baked solution and I am not sure about a lot of things here.

But yeah `./gradlew assembleDebug` and other commands works fine now.